# How to convert a 64bit hex number to binary in Scala?

Tags: scala

I want to convert the following hash "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e" to binary string. However, I can't seem to find a way to do that? Can someone teach me how I can do it in Scala? Thanks

Comment: What encoding to you expect? UTF-8? ASCII?

Comment: UTF-8. Actually I am not even sure if using MessageDigest's MD5 gives a 64 bit hash. I just need a 64 bit hash

Comment: So what should the output type be? a `String`? So you want to parse back your MD5 into the bytes of a string? That can be invalid UTF-8.

Comment: MessageDigest MD5 returns 128 bits, just like your heximal string is 128 bits.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`BigInt`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.BigInt):

```
scala> BigInt("d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e", 16).toString(2)
res0: String = 11010100000111011000110011011001100011110000000010110010000001001110100110000000000010011001100011101100111110000100001001111110
```

The `16` above means the string should be parsed in hex (base 16), and the `2` means the output string should be in binary (base 2).

If you want to dump the raw binary out to a file, you can convert the `BigInt` to a byte array and dump that:

```
scala> BigInt("d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e", 16).toByteArray
res1: Array[Byte] = Array(0, -44, 29, -116, -39, -113, 0, -78, 4, -23, -128, 9, -104, -20, -8, 66, 126)
```

Note that this gives you back 17 bytes instead of the 16 you'd expect for a 128-bit hash. That's because BigInt is a signed value, so it pads the byte array with an extra `0` in the most-significant-byte place to keep the value from being interpreted as negative. You could use `res1.takeRight(16)` to grab only the 16 bytes you're probably interested in.

Comment: It also loses padding zeroes.